# How to use defined in class file with namespace

Tags: php, wordpress, constants

Here is my code.

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

namespace JSR;

class myClass{
...
}
```

This is giving below error

```
Global code should be enclosed in global namespace declaration
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `namespace JSR;` is the first line in code

Comment: It is as in the code.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI or do you mean I should place namespace at the top of everything?

Comment: yes name space should be the first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this...

```
namespace JSR;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

class myClass{
...
}
```